# Combine 2 values to 1 column MySQL

Tags: mysql

### Code:

```
SELECT s.*, k.address FROM student s
INNER JOIN address k
ON instr(s.fulladdress, k.address) > 0
WHERE j.phonetic like '%california%'
```

This result will display 2 rows with 2 parts of address:

```
30,Andre Hans, Address 1 Address 2,class IBA1001, Address 1

30,Andre Hans, Address 1 Address 2,class IBA1001, Address 2
```

I want to display it in 1 row:

```
30,Andre Hans, Address 1 Address 2,class IBA1001, Address 1 | Address 2
```

How i can do that?

Comment: Use `group_concat` -- lots of examples out there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group by` and `group_concat`:

```
SELECT s.*, group_concat(k.address separator ' | ') FROM student s
INNER JOIN address k
ON instr(s.fulladdress, k.address) > 0
WHERE j.phonetic like '%california%' 
GROUP BY s.col1, s.col2 ....  -- all the columns in table student
```